# Integrating Stripe checkout in Code Igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

How do I integrate Stripe payments into a Code Igniter project?

Which is better to use - a CI merchant or omni pay?

I am using simple check out with stripe.js and its working in raw php. Now I need to know how to integrate it into my CI project.

Comment: What exactly is holding you back with using in CI? You can just use the same code and structure in OOP to use in CI.

Comment: You should use Omnipay. Because, it has a clear and consistent API, is fully unit tested, and even comes with an example application to get you started.